# CSS Submenu background on hover

Tags: css, background

I want to make a small website for myself and so I ask this question as a beginner. I cannot succeed to have the submenu contain another background when hovering the main menu.

HTML:

```
        <div id="nav">
            <ul class="sub1">
              <li><a href="#"><h2>Home</h2></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><h2>About</h2></a><!---id="onlink"--->
                <ul class="sub2">
                  <li><a href="#" title="About Us">Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" title="About Our product">Our product</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav{
width:100%;
height: 60px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#nav ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
width: 60%;
margin: auto;

}

#nav ul li{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style: none;
float:left;
position:relative;
background:transparent url(EN/Button_menu_unselected.png);
}

#nav ul li ul li{
background:aqua; /*Test that doesn't work*/
}

#nav ul li a{
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
height:20px;
width:100px;
padding:10px;
display:block;
color:#003300;
}

#nav ul ul{
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul{
visibility:visible;
}

#nav ul li:hover a{
background-image: url(EN/Button_menu_rollover.png);
}
```

The drop down items get the same format as the button called "Button_menu_rollover", which gives me a very bad result.

Comment: try first `background:red;`. I do not think that aqua is a valid css color

Comment: It is, I used it before and it automatically appears (I'm using Coda).

Comment: works ... sorry for that

Comment: tried your code. I see the aqua bg for the 2'nd submenu. It overlaps the button but you correct that with `margin-top:13px;` to `#nav ul ul`

Comment: Uh? This just puts a margin on the top of the drop down for me... indeed, this is the effect that I get. Very strange that I couldn't find an easy fix anywhere...

Comment: so it works now? you solved it?

Comment: No it doesn't actually... The button appears on the aqua background in the submenu... that is the effect that I have. Instead I just want the aqua to appear, so I can customize in anyway I prefer. Perhaps I didn't make myself clear enough, sorry for that.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. The drop down menu has an aqua color background. What do you want it to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
#nav ul li:hover a{
background-image: url(EN/Button_menu_rollover.png);
}
```

is applied to all elements and sub-elements.

This fixes it, but this code does not work on IE6:

```
#nav ul li:hover > a{
background: #fff;
}
```

Or you may use Javascript for HOVER effect to get exact results.

Comment: Oh, so that's where the little arrows are for :-) Many thanks and too bad for the internet explorer 6 for now! I'm planning to improve my design later on, so I'll look into it again afterwards!